# How to get the exception object thrown in the default

Tags: python, exception

I know that we can get the exception object if we use the 'as' syntax:-

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print "can not divide zero"
    print(str(e))
```

I'd like to capture ***everything*** .... ex:-

```
try:
    1/0
except * as e:
    print "some error"
    print(str(e))
```

Can that be done?

Answer (score 5):

All of Python's exceptions are subclasses of `Exception`, so you want:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print "some error"
    print(str(e))
# Output:
some error
integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: This is of course the correct answer, but always be wary of suppressing `Exception`!

Answer (score 0):

Catch Exception like

```
except Exception, e:
```

Comment: This syntax works but is only around for backwards compatibility: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html